# JMeter "If controller" with boolean var

Tags: java, jmeter

I have a `BeanShell` assertion in `Jmeter` and one of the vars is `boolean`.

I'm trying to use If controller and i want it will execute the http request if the var is true.
this is the condition i wrote:

```
${todo} == true
```

todo is the boolean var in the beanshell assertion, and it is not executing the request.

what is wrong with my condition?

thanks.

Comment: Can you show how you're storing `todo` in beanshell?

Comment: i understood my mistake and you right, the prob was exactly in the way i stored in beanshell. works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter use in condition is correct. The problem likely lies with how you're storing the value of todo. Use a debug sampler to verify the value of todo variable.